# How to set value of select with node Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, automation, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I am trying to do some automation with the rather new GoogleChrome/puppeteer library, but I cannot figure out how to set a value in a select field.

Here is my (simplified) function to set the value of a text input:

```
async function setInputVal(sel, text) {
    await page.focus(sel)        
    page.press('Backspace')
    page.type(text)
}

await setInputVal('input.searchjob', task.id)
```

I cant figure out how to do the same for a select field.

I have tried to set the focus, insert script and execute but I cannot get it working.

Comment: Just as a follow-up: puppeteer does have a [first-class API](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.4.0/docs/api.md#pageselectselector-values) for this now.

Comment: linked - [select an option from dropdown select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45864516/104380)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`page.select()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselectselector-values) to `select` an `option`:

```
await page.select('select#example', 'carrot');
```

Answer (score 12):

I found a solution myself:

```
async function setSelectVal(sel, val) {
    page.evaluate((data) => {
        return document.querySelector(data.sel).value = data.val
    }, {sel, val})
}

await setSelectVal('#select_id', 'newValue')
```