# Selecting an option from drop down which is not implemented using Select using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, puppeteer

The React AntD design has a drop down implementation that doesn't use the `Select` tag to implement a drop down. One example is [here](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/) . I have a similar implementation in one of our projects.

[image: AntD Drop Down]

The options from the drop down are populated using the `ul` and `li` tags as shown in the image -

[image: Selection implementation]

How to handle or select any option via an index on this drop down?

For `Select` , we can use `page.select()` method as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864516/how-to-select-an-option-from-dropdown-select) SO discussion. I tried this but this drop down selection doesn't work.

I tried another approach where I used the `page.keyboard.type('ArrowDown')` and `page.keyboard.type('Enter')` to click and use the keys to go to an option but doing this returns `TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function` error.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [example link](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/) that you have given, first, you must click the dropdown link to generate the dropdown list.

Afterwards, you can click the dropdown menu item link by index:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  const dropdown_link = document.querySelector('#components-dropdown-demo-trigger .ant-dropdown-link');

  dropdown_link.click();

  const dropdown_menu_item_links = document.querySelectorAll('.ant-dropdown > .ant-dropdown-menu > .ant-dropdown-menu-item > a');

  dropdown_menu_item_links[0].click(); // Select Menu Item Link by Index
});
```

Comment: I am confused whether to accept this solution or not. I tried the same with the platform I have and it selects the option from the drop down. However, other steps like `page.type` after this are not executed. Any reason why that would happen?

Comment: @demouser123 Since Puppeteer is navigating to a different page (clicking the link in the dropdown menu), you should be able to place `await page.waitForNavigation();` afterwards, and then you should be able to use `page.type()` on the new page.

Comment: Sorry. I should have been more clear. The solution I implemented was for an internal web platform, that has the same drop down. In my case, there is no navigation to other website.

Comment: @demouser123 In this case, you should be able to use `document.querySelectorAll( '.ant-dropdown > .ant-dropdown-menu > .ant-dropdown-menu-item' )[0].click()` to click an item from the dropdown menu by index (without redirecting to any associated link). Then, you can continue to use `page.type()` on the same page. If this doesn't work, then there may be some event firing on `mousedown` or `mouseup` on the page you are referencing causing unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

The best method would be click [page.click](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options), in your case I will write `page.click('div.ant-dropdown.ant-dropdown-placement-bottomleft')` sorry for the large selector; an ID could help.

Comment: I tested an example using click in https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/, if you need the code let me know.

Comment: This will click on the element right? How do I make a selection?

Comment: Yes, now you implement a new click for the element something like this page.click('div.ant-dropdown.ant-dropdown-placement-bottomleft > ul > li:nth-child(3)');