# CSS selector for source code of <select>...</select>

Tags: javascript, node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer, headless-browser

Here is a snippet of source code with `<select>`. I am struggling to find the right selector:

```
<label class="control-label pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: 100;">
    <small>Show</small>&nbsp;
    <select class="input-sm grid-per-pager" name="per-page">
        <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=10" >10</option>
        <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=20" selected>20</option>
        <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=30" >30</option>
        <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=50" >50</option>
        <option value="https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100" >100</option>
    </select>
    &nbsp;<small>Piece</small>
</label>
```

I would like to select the option of `per_page=100` for `page.click()` in Puppeteer. The following selector tried was not correct and error was `node not found`.

```
"select[value='https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100']"
```

Comment: You want to select the `option` not the `select` right?

Comment: `option[value='https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100']` should work, altough styling `select`s and `option`s is notoriously difficult and very limited.. (Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)

Comment: `Philip`, the selector will tell `page.click(selector)` where to click. Error is the node not found.

Comment: If you need javascript to select a certain option, it's safer to set the `select`s `.selectedIndex` to the right option's index than using a (simulated) click. (Or use `.val()` if you're using jQuery.)

Comment: Docs: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp and http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I am using `puppeteer` which is kind of unforgiving.

Comment: So maybe I'm not really understanding your question. Could you elaborate on what your trying to do? And some more context?

Comment: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.9.0&show=api-pageclickselector-options. This is the doc about `page.click(selector)`. I need to have the right selector for the function.

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435873/2142071

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select an option from dropdown select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864516/how-to-select-an-option-from-dropdown-select)

Comment: I read this post you provided before but somehow I did not get it right.

Comment: Did `await page.select('select[name="per-page"]', 'https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100')` not work?

Comment: `page.select('select#per-page', 'https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100');` this seems to work finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following selector for the `option` element:

```
option[value="https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100"]
```

Otherwise, you might be able to shorten the selector to something more concise if it is the only element on the page with a `value` that ends with `per_page=100`:

```
[value$="per_page=100"]
```

Note that you can use the built-in [`page.select()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselectselector-values) function to select an `option` from a `select` element in Puppeteer, but you will need to pass the selector of the `select` element and the `value` of the `option` element:

```
await page.select('select[name="per-page"]', 'https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100');
```

Comment: `option[value="https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100"]`` in `page.click` did not find the node. `page.select(.....)` works.

Answer (score 1):

## [HTMLOptionsCollection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection)

Use the **HTMLOptionsCollection API** and assign a `.class` to it. The following demo locates the last `<option>` of the `<select>`, assigns it a `.class`, and changes its `background-color` to `tomato` red.

---

### Demo

```js
var opts = document.querySelector('.input-sm').options;
opts[opts.length -1].classList.add('lastOpt');
document.querySelector('.lastOpt').style.background = 'tomato';
```

```html
<label class="control-label pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: 100;">

        <small>Show</small>&nbsp;
        <select class="input-sm grid-per-pager" name="per-page">
            <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=10" >10</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=20" selected>20</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=30" >30</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=50" >50</option>
<option value="https://www.mysited-com/admin/order?per_page=100" >100</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;<small>Piece</small>
    </label>
```