# Can not select per page option in Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

There is similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864516/how-to-select-an-option-from-dropdown-select) posted and I applied the same technics to a very similar case.  But the solution did not work for me and I have no clue what is causing the error.

Here is `html source code` of per select:

```
<label class="control-label pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px; font-weight: 100;">

        <small>显示</small>&nbsp;
        <select class="input-sm grid-per-pager" name="per-page">
            <option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=10" >10</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=20" selected>20</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=30" >30</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=50" >50</option>
<option value="https://www.mysite-com/admin/order?per_page=100" >100</option>
        </select>
        &nbsp;<small>条</small>
    </label>
```

Since the `select` here is not native HTML element but a `bootstrap` one, I choose to use `page.click`. The code should do 1) click the `select` element and make the options available to choose and 2) choose 100 per page. Here is the code i have:

```
  res = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 60000}),
    page.click('select[name="per-page"]'),  //<=== causing error
  ]);
  res = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 60000}),
    page.click('select[name="per-page"] > option:nth-child(5)'),
  ]);
```

The error is:

```
Error: No node found for selector: select[name="per-page"]
    at assert (C:\d\code\js\wbot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:259:11)
    at Frame.click (C:\d\code\js\wbot\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:704:5)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

Tried different selectors, such as

```
select.input-sm[name="per-page"]  
select.input-sm.grid-per-pager
```

But none of them works. The selector seems right to me but it can not locate the element. Also tried `page.select` and it did not work as well. What is I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await page.waitForSelector('select[name="per-page"]')
```

waits for the element to show up before select.