# How to select an element of a dropdown list (PUPPETEER)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How to select an element of a dropdown list?
Here is my code:

```
await page.select("#cboTypeMess", "3")
```

to select:

```
<select id="cboTypeMess" name="cboTypeMess" 
`onchange="javascript:DoPostBack('GKfUxv0u+6p3itjfUI4rBsk6/l8+TspfMKgWMhPlzDZa+1fOPN7aOvWgsWUgAs4VNDWAXOxhtluVHrmGMZEI9js/vcWlc8acqwuMHy+oxU9OG9Zr','','',false,true);">
<option value="1" selected="">Individu
</option><option value="3">Groupe
</option></select>
```

Is there a way to change the selected option (like click on Individu button/value 1?

Comment: This tiny snippet of HTML probably doesn't make the example reproducible -- it's not clear that it's even visible when your code runs. Can you share the actual page (or a representative [mcve]) and desired result? The code you gave [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864516/how-to-select-an-option-from-dropdown-select), so what went wrong exactly with it? Also, are you sure you wnat to tag this [tag:java] and not [tag:javascript]? The two are very different languages. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select an option from dropdown select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864516/how-to-select-an-option-from-dropdown-select)