# Getting DOM node text with Puppeteer and headless Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-headless, puppeteer

I'm trying to use headless Chrome and Puppeteer to run our Javascript tests, but I can't extract the results from the page. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45799744/4794), it looks like I should use [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args). That section even has an example that looks like what I need.

```
const bodyHandle = await page.$('body');
const html = await page.evaluate(body => body.innerHTML, bodyHandle);
await bodyHandle.dispose();
```

As a full example, I tried to convert that to a script that will extract my name from my user profile on Stack Overflow. Our project is using Node 6, so I converted the `await` expressions to use `.then()`.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(function(browser) {
    browser.newPage().then(function(page) {
        page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/users/4794').then(function() {
            page.$('h2.user-card-name').then(function(heading_handle) {
                page.evaluate(function(heading) {
                    return heading.innerText;
                }, heading_handle).then(function(result) {
                    console.info(result);
                    browser.close();
                }, function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    browser.close();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

When I run that, I get this error:

```
$ node get_user.js 
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)
    at args.map.x (/mnt/data/don/git/Kive/node_modules/puppeteer/node6/helper.js:30:43)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function.evaluationString (/mnt/data/don/git/Kive/node_modules/puppeteer/node6/helper.js:30:29)
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/mnt/data/don/git/Kive/node_modules/puppeteer/node6/FrameManager.js:376:31)
    at next (native)
    at step (/mnt/data/don/git/Kive/node_modules/puppeteer/node6/FrameManager.js:355:24)
    at Promise (/mnt/data/don/git/Kive/node_modules/puppeteer/node6/FrameManager.js:373:12)
    at fn (/mnt/data/don/git/Kive/node_modules/puppeteer/node6/FrameManager.js:351:10)
    at Frame._rawEvaluate (/mnt/data/don/git/Kive/node_modules/puppeteer/node6/FrameManager.js:375:3)
```

The problem seems to be with serializing the input parameter to `page.evaluate()`. I can pass in strings and numbers, but not element handles. Is the example wrong, or is it a problem with Node 6? How can I extract the text of a DOM node?

Comment: Passing an ElementHandle as an argument into `page.evaluate` was only recently added in https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/commit/9292a56eafabf8dbe8ef0fb0fffe0db0ca4020eb.

Your code will work in the next release of Puppeteer.

Comment: Bad timing on my part, I guess. Thanks for the explanation, @Joel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found three solutions to this problem, depending on how complicated your extraction is. The simplest option is a related function that I hadn't noticed: [`page.$eval()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args). It basically does what I was trying to do: combines `page.$()` and `page.evaluate()`. Here's an example that works:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(function(browser) {
    browser.newPage().then(function(page) {
        page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/users/4794').then(function() {
            page.$eval('h2.user-card-name', function(heading) {
                return heading.innerText;
            }).then(function(result) {
                console.info(result);
                browser.close();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

That gives me the expected result:

```
$ node get_user.js 
Don Kirkby top 2% overall
```

I wanted to extract something more complicated, but I finally realized that the evaluation function is running *in the context of the page*. That means you can use any tools that are loaded in the page, and then just send strings and numbers back and forth. In this example, I use jQuery in a string to extract what I want:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(function(browser) {
    browser.newPage().then(function(page) {
        page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/users/4794').then(function() {
            page.evaluate("$('h2.user-card-name').text()").then(function(result) {
                console.info(result);
                browser.close();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

That gives me a result with the whitespace intact:

```
$ node get_user.js 

                            Don Kirkby

                                top 2% overall
```

In my real script, I want to extract the text of several nodes, so I need a function instead of a simple string:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.launch().then(function(browser) {
    browser.newPage().then(function(page) {
        page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/users/4794').then(function() {
            page.evaluate(function() {
                return $('h2.user-card-name').text();
            }).then(function(result) {
                console.info(result);
                browser.close();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

That gives the exact same result. Now I need to add error handling, and maybe reduce the indentation levels.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`await/async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and [`$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1), the syntax looks like the following:

```
await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/users/4794')
const nameElement = await context.page.$eval('h2.user-card-name', el => el.text())
console.log(nameElement)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to do this in Node 6 without async and await.

Comment: Just put it into babel when that happens.

Comment: I don't think the returned DOM element will include a `text()` method; you'd probably want to use innerText

Comment: What's up with the `context` here?

Comment: `context` is usually given to you when creating the puppeteer instance. The API may have changed since writing, however.

Answer (score 3):

I use page.$eval

```
const text = await page.$eval('h2.user-card-name', el => el.innerText );
console.log(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had success using the following:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
try {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  await page.waitFor(2000);
  let html_content = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$('.element-class-name'));
  console.log(html_content);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Hope it helps.